# How do I set all bits to 1 or zero depends on original number

Tags: c

I would like to know how to set all bits to either one or zero depends on the original number (signed integers are safe). For example,

```
int filter = !!number; //return either 1 or zero and I would like to set all bits of filter to either one or zero depends on filter.
```

I would like to set all bits of 'filter' only by using these operator (! ~ & ^ | + << >>)

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: The "set to 0" case is clear, isn't it?

Comment: When you say “set all bits to 1”, is −1 okay? It’s not ones’-complement-safe, but…

Comment: Yes it is okay to have 2's complement

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking: what do you mean by "depends on the original number"? And what do you mean by "return either 1 or zero"? You want to set all bits of `filter` to 1 or 0, then what is returning 1 or 0? Or you want to set all bits of `number` to 1 or 0? Please clarify.

Comment: I would like to set All bits of 'filter'

Comment: `!` is not a bitwise operator. Why is it on your list?

Comment: Are the parentheses are included in your list of usable operators?  If so, are you asked to use only algorithmic solutions, or is an if statement available to you?  Are you allowed to assume the size of the int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 2's compliment for integer representation:

```
int filter = number ?-1 :0;
```

or (referring to the question's rev 2))

```
int filter = !number -1;
```

or

```
int filter = !number + (-1); /* Does not use the - operator. */
```

or

```
int filter = !number + (union {unsigned u; int i;}){UINT_MAX}.i;
```

<sup>(Not sure if the latter invoked UB.)</sup>

or, reminded by [Kamil's (deleted) comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680736/how-do-i-set-all-bits-to-1-or-zero-depends-on-original-number#comment92290220_52680771):

```
int filter = !number + ~0;
```

<sup>(Should work in any case)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! but I am not allowed to use the minus operator.

Comment: `!` is not a bitwise operator.

Comment: @DYZ The question lists `!` as an allowed operator. If anything, the question should be edited to not call it bitwise.

Comment: I mean the above operators (! ~ & ^ | + << >>), I'm sorry for being unclear

Comment: The question was unclear. The OP says _using the bitwise operator_ and then has `!` on the list. I am not questioning the validity of the answer.